# Redeclaring variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Is it necessary to empty variables before reassigning them?

For example, I have an object 'user'.

```
$random_user = new User();
```

If I declare several $random_users, the object will not keep its old values, it will just be entirely rewritten correct?

Comment: try the function `var_dump()`. When you just dump the `$random_user` before and after a redeclaration you would have known :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you redeclare $random_user, the value will be completely overridden:

```
$random_user = new User();
$random_user = new User(); // entirely different object
$random_user = 10; // now an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just "overwrite" the variable with a new value. All the old data will be forgotten. For example:

```
$var = 1;
echo $var; // Will output 1
$var = 2; // Overrules $var with 2, 1 will be dropped entirely
echo $var; // Will output 2
```

The same goes for objects that you put in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You don't need to empty variables before reassigning them, just reassign them, the object without `refCount` will be destroyed by php Garbage Collection.

```
$random_user = new User();
$random_user = new User(); 
$random_user = new User(); // the first two User object will be destroyed by GC
```